# Vapi-xp library properties of TDAPIOLELIB are disabled

Tags: testing, hp-quality-center

We are writing the vb scripts in Vapi-xp (in QC) to execute the Shell scripts in unix box.
At present, Vapi calls the functional library in the local to run shell scripts.
As part of enhancements to Frame Work , we trying to attach the Functional library in ALM(QC) and  to download the same to local at run-time.

To Download the attachment  from ALM to local:  We  tried to use TDAPIOLELIB reference library in Vapi-xp But most of the Properties like Treemanager are Disabled.

So anyone knows the fix to above problem.please let us know

Is there any better approach to download the attachments from vapi-xp?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to download from inside vapi-xp, but you can have the ALM deployment engine deploy your files from ALM server the same way as it deploys the rest of the ALM client.

For detailed instructions on how to make it work look for the custom test types guide in ALM documentation. 
There in the deployment section you have instructions on packaging your files and placing them on ALM server for download.

Answer (score 0):

We have used the OTA client library to download the VAPI-XP scripts.

The `IExtendedStorage` interface is used in getting the downloads.

Using the Rest API, the following URL downloads the scripts in VAPI-XP:

```
/rest/domains/DEFAULT/projects/<project_name>/tests/<test_id>/storage?login-form-required=y
```

e.g.

```
/rest/domains/DEFAULT/projects/sample/tests/6/storage?login-form-required=y
```